# Popup customizado

Tags: android

Estou querendo fazer um popup customizado, parecido com esse da foto, colocando um botão para fechar no topo e ele centralizado no meio da tela, alguem sabe como eu faço isso?
Procurei alguns códigos, mas nada muito completo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse seu exemplo tem grande chance (pela aparência) de ser não verdade um Popup(Modal) Web. Carregado a partir de um WebView do Android, ou pode até mesmo ser fruto de uma aplicação hibrida produzida com [PhoneGap (ou alguma variação)](http://phonegap.com/). Na verdade estou falando isso, por que o layout do [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) é um pouco complicado de se customizar(até onde o conheço), e acredito que esse Popup não seja construído de forma nativa no Android. E se você deseja programar de forma nativa não será possível reproduzi-lo

Comment: Fernando, é possível sim customizar o Dialog dessa forma, basta tirar o título e os botões. E usando uma `Custom View`. Nessa pergunta/resposta tem um exemplo de código completo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173855/android-alertdialog-with-custom-view-and-rounded-corners.

Comment: Uhuh, legal @Wakim, não conhecia, e não acreditava que isso era possível com tão pouco trabalho, já tinha procurado algo similar a isso, não tão "radical" quanto a pergunta, mas não tinha obtido sucesso, e deixei para o futuro já que não era algo fundamente nesse momento para o aplicativo, até por isso a pergunta me chamou atenção. Irei pesquisar um pouco mais sobre o assunto. E obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @Fernando, ok! As vezes eu marcava e o próprio SO removia as marcações, não sei se era momentâneo. Valeu pelo aviso.

Comment: Wakim obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu precisava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com DialogFragment você consegue dessa forma abaixo

```
mButton.setOnclickListener(new OnclickListener(){
       test();

});

public void test(){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.seu_layout_customizado);
    dialog.show();
}
```

**Criação do XML**

- Cria um root LinearLayout
- Cria um outro LinearLayout com a orientação na vertical, onde vai conter o botão do X, o título e a descrição.
- Cria uma View (`<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp"/>`) para representar a linha. Para representar esse agrupamento de ícones e texto (gps, wifi e rede sem fio) cria um RelativeLayout.
- Para o botão de confirmação, adiciona na LinearLayout root.

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="x"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Melhore..."/>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Para garantir..."/>
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      gps
      rede
      wifi
      </RelativeLayout>
  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  ```

Comment: Douglas, só falta incluir `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` nessa solução. Senão o `Dialog` vai colocar uma barra pro título.

Comment: Verdade, sem adicionar o `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` é criado com a barra de título.